# hydro Gazebo on a Jenkins -> FAILURE: Test Fixture Nodes [...] failed to spawn

Tags: gazebo, jenkins, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running a gazebo simulation on a **jenkins** server under **hydro**. I have an issue there. 
I ***do not*** have this problem when I am either:

- running the simulation locally
- using groovy (on the server, too)

This is the relevant output:

```
spawn_model script started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1405355874.601154] [0.000000] Loading model xml from ros parameter
[INFO] [WallTime: 1405355874.614810] [0.000000] Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
spawn_model script started
[INFO] [WallTime: 1405355874.602682] [0.000000] Loading model xml from ros parameter
[INFO] [WallTime: 1405355874.626550] [0.000000] Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
... logging to /root/.ros/log/rostest-jenkins-aub-ch-24428.log
[ROSUNIT] Outputting test results to /tmp/src/wet/build/test_results/my_navigation_test/rostest-launch_my_test_param_test___navigation_arg__2dnav_ipa_eband-navigation_ipa__true-robot__cob3-6-robot_env__ipa-kitchen-scenarioName__scene2-sim__true-.xml
testnavigation_test_jenkins_aub_ch_24428_6280624626160673722 ... FAILURE!
FAILURE: Test Fixture Nodes ['world_joint_state_publisher', 'joint_state_controller_spawner', 'base_controller_spawner', 'head_controller_spawner', 'arm_controller_spawner', 'sdh_controller_spawner', 'torso_controller_spawner', 'tray_controller_spawner'] failed to launch
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 327, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/tmp/src/wet/src/ros_comm/tools/rostest/src/rostest/runner.py", line 122, in fn
    self.assert_(not failed, "Test Fixture Nodes %s failed to launch"%failed)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 420, in assertTrue
    raise self.failureException(msg)
```

I think this problem depends on the `/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model` service.
Any Ideas, how to fix this?
Thanks for your help!

### Update:

I now looked deeper into the problem: I reinstalled all dependencies from apt packages using `ros-hydro-desktop-full`
I found an error in the logfile of `world_state_publisher`:

```
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher
[33m[ WARN] [1406034138.074698487]: The 'state_publisher' executable is deprecated. Please use 'robot_state_publisher' instead[0m
[33m[ WARN] [1406034138.106214435]: The root link dummy_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.[0m
```

It turns out that this link is actually missing in the simulated robot model. 
Can anybody help me on that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186598/hydro-gazebo-on-a-jenkins--%3E-failure:-test-fixture-nodes-%5B...%5D-failed-to-spawn/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-07-17**:
Has no one an idea? Can you maybe give me an idea what I should check? What can be different between the case of launching it locally and on a jenkins server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**FYI**: This was basically a big dependency problem. It was solved here: http://answers.ros.org/question/187417/problem-running-gazebo-failed-to-load-plugin-libgazebo_ros_controlso/?answer=187418#post-id-187418 (Plus by adding several more missing dependencies)

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0